# Can we provide link of the md in the Markdown to reStructuredText converter rather than the file path?

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I used the converter [m2r2](https://github.com/CrossNox/m2r2) but it only renders the md which is provided to it as a file in the mdinclude directive like this

```
.. mdinclude:: ./md/Readme.md
```

but we can't provide a remote link of the md like

```
.. mdinclude:: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md
```

It doesn't render the md provided to it as a remote link and gives the following error because it's looking for a file or directory in the local only [image: Error]

Is there a way we can render md inside rst by providing a link of the md rather than downloading it on the local and providing a relative path? Is there any other directive, package or way of doing it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sure, providing a path to a MD file works like this `.. mdinclude:: ./md/Readme.md`, it renders the provided md file in the rst but is there a way we can provide a remote link to the md rather than the file or directory path. To illustrate more, can we render this md https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/README in our rst doc without downloading it on the local and providing path of it to the rst. Please share a way to do it if you know.

Comment: I've edited the question for more clarity with an error message.

Comment: Also asked here: https://github.com/CrossNox/m2r2/issues/51

Comment: Yes, it's asked by me only. @mzjn